# Email not send using apex via visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

im using this code to sending mail but no mail was send.What is wrong
Thanks in advance.

```
   List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

   for(ResultWrapper wrapper: lstResultWrapper)
   {
       if(wrapper.isSelected == true)
       {
           results.add(wrapper.objResult);
       }
   }

   EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'Contact: Follow Up (SAMPLE)'];    
   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id); 
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

   List<String> toAddress= new List<String>();
   for(Result r: results)
   {
        toAddress.add(r.ins);
   }

   mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
   allmsg.add(mail);        
   Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
```

**I am trying to send email to external users**

Comment: `Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);` instead use `Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);`.. If you use like this then you  will get error.  After that update your question with error.

Comment: you need to use `targetObjectId`.. If you want use `setTemplateID` then you  have to use `targetObjectId`.

Comment: @Ratan what is targetObjectId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use EmailTemplate then you have to use `setTemplateID`.

`setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)`

> Required if using a template, optional otherwise. The ID of the
>   contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent. The ID you
>   specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in the template
>   contain the correct data.

---

In you case you are trying to send email to external user..

So you need to use `setHtmlBody` or `setplainTextBOdy` methods for email body.

```
   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
   mail.setSubject('stackforce answer');
   mail.setplainTextBOdy('Test');
   List<String> toAddress= new List<String>();
   toAddress.add('test@gmail.com');
   mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
   allmsg.add(mail);        
   Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);
```

using `setHtmlBody`

**Example**

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'foo@bar.com'});
mail.setSubject('stackforce answer');
String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi, welcome to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Our World</body>  </html>';
mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);
```

instead of `Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);`
at least you will know what error you are getting.

Comment: This is not an ans to the question. if you want ask anything ask in comment